# Xpages view panel - How to Open New Browser Tab

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

**To do:**

1. I want my view panel to open mail that send.
2. i able to open the mailbox, but i not be able to open it new tab, even i update the view with "_blank"

[image: Open]
**Script:**
I put the script in "At runtime, open selected document using"

```
var ve:NotesViewEntry = rowData;
if (ve.isDocument()) {
    var doc:NotesDocument = ve.getDocument();

    var unid = doc.getItemValue("Notification_UNID2");
    if (unid != null && unid != "") {
        var trimmed = @Trim(unid);
        if (trimmed != "") {
            var mailsetdoc:NotesDocument = database.getProfileDocument("Mail Settings", "");
            var mailinsvr = mailsetdoc.getItemValueString("MailInDbSvr");
            var mailinpath = mailsetdoc.getItemValueString("MailInDbPath");
            var mailindb = session.getDatabase(mailinsvr, mailinpath, false);
            try {
                var notifydoc:NotesDocument = mailindb.getDocumentByUNID(trimmed);
                if (notifydoc != null) {
                    @ClientType() == "Notes" ? notifydoc.getNotesURL() : notifydoc.getHttpURL(); 
                }
            } catch(e) {
                if (@ClientType() == "Notes") {
                    "notes://" + @Name("[CN]", database.getServer()) + "/" + database.getFilePath().replace("\\", "/") + "/notification_deleted.xsp?OpenXPage";
                } else {
                    database.getHttpURL().replace("?OpenDatabase", "/notification_deleted.xsp");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**sample photo:**

[image: mail]
*This is list of person email image

[image: property]

*This is properties of photo

Comment: Did you verify that the list entries contain the correct links (right-click the entry in the browser and select "Inspect element")? If this looks fine you should check if you have a popup-blocker active that might prevent the new tab from being opened.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the URL into javascript code, that launches the URL into new window/tab, but stays in current page.

Something like this:

```
javascript:window.open('YOUR URL HERE','_blank');void(0);
```